# Can Cronbach’s alpha be used to assess the equivalence of two different questionnaires?

Tags: correlation, survey, pearson-r, equivalence

I have a very simple quality-of-life (QOL) questionnaire that is much easier to implement than two currently used in practice and a longitudinal data set in which patients were administered all three questionnaires at each visit.  I'd like to show that the new/short questionnaire is equivalent to the old/long questionnaires as a measure of QOL and as a result can be used in place of the old/long questionnaires.  The three measures are all on different scales (two are sums of a different number of Likert-scale questions, the other is a continuous measure).

Is there a standard way to show an equivalence between two different questionnaires?

Does it make sense to use Cronbach’s alpha to argue that the three questionnaires are consistent with each other within a given visit, followed by factor analysis to show that they are uni-dimensional?  Or is this analysis as simple as calculating the Pearson correlation coefficient between the measures?